# How to print object as json in jsrender

Tags: jsrender

I am new to jsrender, so how to print array of object as json

```
            <ul>{{for my_array}}
                 <li>{{:.toString()}}</li>
                {{/for}}
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [{{props}} tag](http://www.jsviews.com/#propstag) doc topic.

You can also use the {{jsonview}} tag control - see the JsViews topics:

- http://www.jsviews.com/#jsvpropstag
- http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/tag-controls/jsonview

{{jsonview}} can be used with JsRender (i.e. without doing JsViews data binding) as in this example:

```
<head>
  ...
  <script src="//www.jsviews.com/download/jsrender.js"></script>
  <script src="//www.jsviews.com/download/sample-tag-controls/jsonview/jsonview.js"></script>
  <link href="//www.jsviews.com/download/sample-tag-controls/jsonview/jsonview.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div id="team"></div>

<script id="myTmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
{{jsonview/}}
</script>

<script>
"use strict";
var team = {
  members: {
    m1: {name: "Robert"},
    m2: {name: "Sarah"}
  }
};

$("#team").html($.templates("#myTmpl").render(team));

</script>
</body>
```